# How to determine if a TreeItem is a leaf or not

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a JFace `TreeViewer` wherein the user can select a `TreeItem` and check whether ist a leaf node or not through a menu option.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the currently selected object from the tree viewer with:

```
IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)viewer.getSelection();

Object selected = selection.getFirstElement();
```

where 'viewer' is the `TreeViewer`

`selected` is your model object as returned by your content provider.

You can use your content provider to test if it has children with:

```
ITreeContentProvider provider = (ITreeContentProvider)viewer.getContentProvider();

boolean hasChildren = provider.hasChildren(selected);
```